# Different yaml inputs for CWL scatter

Tags: yaml

I have a commandline tool in `cwl` which can take the following input:

```
fastq:
    class: File
    path: /path/to/fastq_R1.fq.gz
fastq2:
    class: File
    path: /path/to/fastq_R2.fq.gz
sample_name: foo
```

Now I want to scatter over this commandline tool and the only way I can think to do it is with `scatterMethod: dotproduct` and an input of something like:

```
fastqs:
    - class: File
      path: /path/to/fastq_1_R1.fq.gz
    - class: File
      path: /path/to/fastq_2_R1.fq.gz
fastq2s:
    - class: File
      path: /path/to/fastq_1_R2.fq.gz
    - class: File
      path: /path/to/fastq_2_R2.fq.gz
sample_names: [foo, bar]
```

Is there any other way for me to design the workflow and / or input file such that each input group is sectioned together? Something like

```
paired_end_fastqs:
    - fastq:
          class: File
          path: /path/to/fastq_1_R1.fq.gz
      fastq2:
          class: File
          path: /path/to/fastq_1_R2.fq.gz
      sample_name: foo
    - fastq:
          class: File
          path: /path/to/fastq_2_R1.fq.gz
      fastq2:
          class: File
          path: /path/to/fastq_2_R2.fq.gz
      sample_name: bar
```

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish this with a nested workflow wrapper that maps a record to each individual field, and then using that workflow to scatter over an array of records. The workflow would look something like this:

```
---
class: Workflow
cwlVersion: v1.0
id: workflow
inputs:
- id: paired_end_fastqs
  type:
    type: record
    name: paired_end_fastqs
    fields:
    - name: fastq
      type: File
    - name: fastq2
      type: File
    - name: sample_name
      type: string
outputs: []
steps:
- id: tool
  in:
  - id: fastq
    source: paired_end_fastqs
    valueFrom: "$(self.fastq)"
  - id: fastq2
    source: paired_end_fastqs
    valueFrom: "$(self.fastq2)"
  - id: sample_name
    source: paired_end_fastqs
    valueFrom: "$(self.sample_name)"
  out: []
  run: "./tool.cwl"
requirements:
- class: StepInputExpressionRequirement
```

Specify a workflow input of type record, with fields for each of the inputs the tool accepts, the ones you want to keep together while scattering. Connect the workflow input to each tool input, its `source`. Using `valueFrom` on the step inputs, transform the record (`self` is the `source` this context) to pass only the appropriate field to the tool.

More about `valueFrom` in workflow steps: https://www.commonwl.org/v1.0/Workflow.html#WorkflowStepInput

Then use this wrapper in your actual workflow and scatter over `paired_end_fastqs` with an array of records.